# Date Format Issue, ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am writing this query, to find data between two dates. The time format I have is exactly like the one I am using in the query

```
    select TO_CHAR(REC_NO),(FIRSTNAME ||' '|| LASTNAME) as NAME,
           LOC_NAME,TO_CHAR(START_TIME,'yyyy/mm/dd/HH:MI:SS'),
           TO_CHAR(END_TIME,'yyyy/mm/dd/HH:MI:SS'),
           TT_NO,CUST_ID,CUST_MOB,MAC_ADDR,EMAIL_ID,s.STATUS 
     from vw_rtb_visit_assn v 
left join vu_issue_status@jiradb s on v.TT_NO = s.TICKETNUMBER  and TT_NO = '123' 
      and v.ASSN_TIME between to_date('Tue Dec 16 00:00:00 PKT 2014','yyyy/mm/dd')
      and to_date('Wed Dec 17 00:00:00 PKT 2014','yyyy/mm/dd')
```

My query doesn't execute and gives me a format exception.

Comment: Your `to_date` calls are wrong, you should read the documentation on date formatting: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210

Comment: `to_date('Wed Dec 17 00:00:00 PKT 2014','yyyy/mm/dd')` does not make any sense. The format mask you provide does not even remotely align with the literal.

Comment: You don't have to do any string parsing, just specify the dates as date literals, eg `DATE '2014-12-16'`. A date literal is an actual date value, not a string that needs parsing using a specific format.

Comment: Also, [don't use `BETWEEN` with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (this applies to all positive contiguous-range types - everything except integers).  You should be using an exclusive upper-bound (that is, `<`).  The blog post is using SQL Server (which has a couple extra gotchas given its data types), but remember that Oracle's Timestamp type can be instantiated with different amounts of fractional seconds...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your date are not in actual format of that particular character you pass in where condition

```
to_date('Tue Dec 16 00:00:00 PKT 2014','yyyy/mm/dd')
```

it should be

```
to_date('Tue Dec 16 00:00:00 PKT 2014','DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY')
```

Comment: you should check mavroprovato comment before implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

the format of DATE_IN_CHAR and FORMAT in  to_date('DATE_IN_CHAR','FORMAT') should match.

kindly try the below

```
  and v.ASSN_TIME between to_date('2014/12/16','yyyy/mm/dd')
  and to_date('2014/12/17','yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Answer (score 1):

Dates do not have formats. Formats are used for parsing strings as dates or generating strings from dates. You don't have to do any of these, you simply need to specify the interval as a date literal, as described [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ), eg:

```
  and v.ASSN_TIME between DATE '2014-12-16' AND DATE '2014-12-17'
```

Date literals are actual date values, not strings that have to be parsed using a specific format.

You can also specify TIMESTAMP literals with

```
TIMESTAMP '1997-01-31 09:26:50.124'
```

or

```
TIMESTAMP '1997-01-31 09:26:56.66 +02:00'
```

for a TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE.